# VIM I disabled my arrow keys now how do I navigate through previous commands?

Tags: vim, command-line

I disabled my arrow keys and I am glad I did, just couple of days without them and I hardly miss them, until I discovered that I can type ": < UP > " or ":< DOWN >" and navigate through my previous commands. But now that I disabled them, how do I navigate my those commands? we can't use plain hjkl..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want one command try typing <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> (you can scroll that list with the usual suspects). If you are really using the history, you can find many more details on this page: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_command-line_history

Answer (score 4):

draevor pretty much called it, but I'd like to suggest control-F.

You can type **:** followed by **control-F** to get to the same history that **q:** gets you too.

I like it b/c you can use it for search history too: **/** and then **control-F** or....similarly, **q/**.

I prefer the **/** or **:** because generally I want to do a search or or something in command mode and then realize, "Oh yeah, didn't I already do this once?" Control-F to the rescue!

Comment: That's a one handy piece of info!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `CTRL+p` to go back("up") in the command history, and `CTRL+n` to go forward("down") in the command history. If you want to go left and right - that can't be done without the arrow keys, so you'll have to use `q:` to edit the command history buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my vimrc:

```
 map <up> <nop>
 map <down> <nop>
 map <left> <nop>
 map <right> <nop>
 imap <up> <nop>
 imap <down> <nop>
 imap <left> <nop>
 imap <right> <nop>
```

If you do this way you'll still have arrows working in "command mode".